# Restlet client for WCF webservice

Tags: wcf, restlet

I am looking for sample code restlet client through which I can make WCF webservice(REST) hosted on IIS.

thanks
Adi

Answer (score 0):

From "Restlet in action"

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

public class HelloClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientResource helloClientResource = new ClientResource("http://example.com:8111/");
    helloClientResource.get().write(System.out);
    }
}